# Logo programming language

Tags: software-installation, programming

I want to setup the Logo programming language in Ubuntu 14.04. Can someone please suggest me the appropriate compiler which is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try **KTurtle**:

To install it use `sudo apt-get install kturtle` or Ubuntu software center

Answer (score 5):

LibreOffice now provides a Logo implementation that is truer to vintage Logo than KTurtle.  Install as `sudo apt install libreoffice-librelogo`, and then access its controls by enabling the `Logo` toolbar under `View|Toolbars|Logo` within LibreOffice Writer.  There will also be a `Logo` entry in the `LibreOffice Help` system.

It's well documented and simple to use once you get the hang of it, and feels very much like Apple II logo, and TI-99/4A logo.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, **UCBLogo,** also known as Berkeley Logo, is closest to a 'de facto' standard Logo programming language and is available through the Debian command line package management tool **Advanced Package Tool, APT.** UCBLogo Language code is an interpreted computer language, and does not require an additional complier.

```
To install type: sudo apt-get install ucblogo
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) module that ships with Python!

```
$ python
>>> from turtle import *
>>> forward(100)
```